# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CascadeClassifier' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, opencv

I've been going round in circles for ages trying to figure this out. Why am I getting this attribute error? I've tried using absolute references, and get the same issue. PyCharm is also highlighting CascadeClassifier, cvtColor and COLOR_BGR2GRAY saying it cannot find reference in cv2.py. I'm not sure if more information is relevant to solving this problem, so please ask if more is needed.

```
import cv2
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('read_only/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('read_only/haarcascade_eye.xml')
grayed_images = []
for x in np_images:
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grayed_images.append(gray_img)
    print(x)
```

Comment: do you see `opencv-python` when you run `pip list` command?

Comment: @smttsp Yes, it's present there

Comment: @Carcigenicate No. I called it glibglob so there was no chance of it clashing with anything in the script.

Comment: What does `print(cv2.__dict__)` show?

Comment: Is it the same environment? I think the issue is you might be running your code in a different python environment than the one which has the opencv. Can you try reading an image using `cv2.imread(path/to/image)`

Comment: @smttsp imread is also highlighted by PyCharm saying it cannot find reference in cv2.py

Comment: @Carcigenicate It produces exactly the same error, even everything but the import statements is commented out

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: @smttsp I've tried it on PyCharm, IDLE and command prompt

Comment: Also tried uninstalling opencv and reinstalling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I am correct, you are using an environment different from where you run.

`Step1:` In command line/terminal where you see the `opencv-python` when you run `pip list`:

run `python` command. Copy your code, check if it works (you can simply `import cv2` alternatively)

If it works, my idea should be correct. Otherwise, there is something bigger.

`Step 2:` (Assuming step1 works.) In Pycharm, Under `Run > Edit Configurations`, change `python interpreter` to whichever interpreter is you are that has `opencv`.

`Step2 better alternative:` On Pycharm, open the `terminal`, `pip install opencv-python`. After that you should have the opencv.

Comment: Thank you! This has solved the problem.
I can't upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputation points yet, but I'll be back to do so when I can.

Comment: Hi @smttsp, I am also facing same issue "AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute '_registerMatType' (most likely due to a circular import)". I deploy azure functions using docker file. In requirements.txt I have listed opencv-python. What I need to do to fix it? It was working fine previously, but after removing docker container and rebuild docker file, this error happens.

Answer (score 4):

Downgrade opencv to the version 4.5.5.64.

You can install opencv using
**pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.64**.

This works for me