# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute '_registerMatType' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, opencv, dependencies, mediapipe

- **Here is the source code : **
  `

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import pyautogui
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh.FaceMesh(refine_landmarks=True)
screen_w, screen_h = pyautogui.size()
while True:
    _, frame = cam.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    output = face_mesh.process(rgb_frame)
    landmark_points = output.multi_face_landmarks
    frame_h, frame_w, _ = frame.shape
    if landmark_points:
        landmarks = landmark_points[0].landmark
        for id, landmark in enumerate(landmarks[474:478]):
            x = int(landmark.x * frame_w)
            y = int(landmark.y * frame_h)
            cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 3, (0, 255, 0))
            if id == 1:
                screen_x = screen_w * landmark.x
                screen_y = screen_h * landmark.y
                pyautogui.moveTo(screen_x, screen_y)
        left = [landmarks[145], landmarks[159]]
        for landmark in left:
            x = int(landmark.x * frame_w)
            y = int(landmark.y * frame_h)
            cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 3, (0, 255, 255))
        if (left[0].y - left[1].y) < 0.004:
            pyautogui.click()
            pyautogui.sleep(1)
    cv2.imshow('Eye Controlled Mouse', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

`

- **error log file is as follows:**
  `

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yusra/Documents/test_proj/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/yusra/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/home/yusra/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 175, in bootstrap
    if __load_extra_py_code_for_module("cv2", submodule, DEBUG):
  File "/home/yusra/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 28, in __load_extra_py_code_for_module
    py_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "/home/yusra/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/yusra/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/mat_wrapper/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    cv._registerMatType(Mat)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute '_registerMatType' (most likely due to a circular import)
(base) yusra@yusra-Vostro-3480:~/Documents/test_proj$
```

`
I have tried by uninstalling the openCV and reinstalling the headless version but the proble still exists.
request you to help me out in it :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CascadeClassifier' (most likely due to a circular import)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634520/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-cv2-has-no-attribute-cascadeclas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `opencv-python` and `opencv-python-headless` versions. They should match.

Comment: they should NEVER be installed concurrently. they conflict. remove them all, install exactly one variant.